# Get size of array pointers c++

Tags: pointers, size

How to get the size of array of pointers made it with new double[...]

Using this is works

```
double arr[10];
sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]);
```

but this is not

```
double *arr;
arr=new double[10];
sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]);
```

Answer (score 2):

Initially you declared a double array of size 10.

> ```
> double arr[10];
> ```

And then this statement gives number of array elements in the array. Yes right.

> ```
> sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]);
> ```

In other programme this statement ....

> ```
>  double *arr;
> ```
>
> creates a pointer to double.

And this...

> ```
> arr=new double[10];
> ```
>
> stores the starting address of array in arr.
>   But arr is still a pointer to double.

This statement ...

> ```
> sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]);
> ```
>
> is the culprit. Here *sizeof(arr)* returns **size of the pointer to double** instead of size of array. And sizeof(arr[0]) returns the size of double. Depending on your machine your size of pointer and size of double may be different. But it will print the quotient of the two values.